# I want to remove activity which i show when i press home button

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast

I am working with **one popup(Activity with custom dialog)** display task,

It will be comes on as `per time schedule` that's why i am used `services` and **services trigger Broadcast Receiver** and `BroadCast Receiver trigger my this activity class` which contain **dialog**.

all the working fine popup comes as per time schedule.

**Problem:**

> when my app is close i press home button that time my application with popup screen always open.

I am trying manifest all the entry like `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, `"android:noHistory="true"` and many more.

I think always stack with last activity data but **i am used finish() in poup ok click.**

please give me some guideline.

Comment: I'm not sure about this ... But when you press home button activity call onPause() method ... if you don't want to close your activity . write your code in onPause() maybe it will work ...

Comment: onCreate(),OnResume() all of the call.but i would require remove this screen in homescreen press.

Comment: then write exit code in on pause() (use ....(finish()))

Comment: i am used but not work

Comment: Now what happened ? when u press home Button ?

Comment: @Amsheer user any time press home screen and it will be display in recently app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of `googling` i found out trick.

Check `if popup click` then

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
```

**otherwise**

```
ShowPopup()
```

Thanks @Aarun and @John Carter JC for help me.

Answer (score 0):

> use this intent when you want to show homeScreen

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(setIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can use you can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>
> FirstActivity is the first activity in the application:

```
public static void home(Context ctx) {
    if (!(ctx instanceof FirstActivity)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

> And If you want to exit from the whole application,this help you in
>   that.

```
   public static void clearAndExit(Context ctx) {
    if (!(ctx instanceof FirstActivity)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("exit", true);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        ((Activity) ctx).finish();
    }
}
```

> i Really Hope this helps.

Comment: hey Aaruin how i am used in my dialogactivity?

Comment: this code is used any where in any activity just call the method where you want to finish the activity stack,...

Comment: "when my app is close i press home button that time my application with popup screen always open." make it a bit clear....